# Why does this code work in phpadmin/sql but not in python code?

Tags: python, mysql

The following (working) code I made would dedupe my table of entire rows of duplicate data.

```
DELETE t1 FROM table_name t1
INNER JOIN table_name t2 
WHERE 
    t1.ID < t2.ID AND 
    t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName AND
    t1.Surname = t2.Surname AND  
    t1.Size = t2.Size AND
    t1.Weight = t2.Weight ;
```

So this table:

```
ID  FirstName       Surname         Size        Weight
1   John            Peterson        6           12
2   Paul            Harris          7           11
3   Fred            Flintstone      6           10
4   John            Peterson        6           12
```

becomes:

```
ID  FirstName       Surname         Size        Weight
2   Paul            Harris          7           11
3   Fred            Flintstone      6           10
4   John            Peterson        6           12
```

Rows 1 and 4 are exactly the same so only the newest version (4) is kept.

The code works perfect in my phpadmin sql queries form. I'm struggling to get it working in my python code.

This is my python code:

```
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
tables_list=[]
for table in cursor:
    print(table[0])
    tables_list.append(table[0])

if desired_table_name in tables_list:    
    command = "LOCK TABLES " + desired_table_name + " WRITE, t1 WRITE, t2 WRITE"
    cursor.execute(f"{command}")    
    print("locked table")

    command = "DELETE t1 FROM desired_table_name t1 INNER JOIN desired_table_name t2 WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID AND t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName AND t1.Surname = t2.Surname AND t1.Size = t2.Size AND t1.Weight = t2.Weight"

    cursor.execute(f"{command}")
    print(this_bookie_table_changes_name," was deduped")
    cursor.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")
```

Initially it gave a traceback of t1 and t2 not being locked before use. They don't actually exist. I never set them up. So i put in a lock tables command and now it is correctly complaining the tables don't exist.

I'm a bit lost. How do I get this code to work in my python code. t1 and t2 don't exist either when I run the code in phpadmin sql queries and it definitely works! I suspect my question comes down to what is different between running the code in python and mysql that it works in one but not the other??

Thanks!

Comment: what does *my Python code* look like?  post it, and your exception message, otherwise it's really difficult to say.  I suspect however that you are not committing the implicit transaction.  searching `[python] commit [mysql]` here should give you some more background.  I'd also get rid of the trailing `;`.

Comment: did you also lock the tables in phpmyadmin, or did you run simply the delete code

Comment: You need to lock `t1` and `t2` for READ and `t1` for WRITE. You do not need to lock `desired_table_name`. You may test locking in PHPadmin.

Comment: you can't really avoid string concatenation in this, since parametrized procedures don't handle SQL components like key words or table/column names.  however, if this is a live app and the table names come from somewhere not fully trusted, you might want to check them to avoid sql injection.  at a guess, I'd flag for any character **not** in acceptable table name chars `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, probably.

Comment: out of curiosity, does **mysql** really, really, need explicit locking in this context?  that seems excessively wonky in 2020.  I know DB2, back in the 00's tended to refuse executing self-referential insert/update/delete like this, but that was only in 2000s and only DB2 -- not MSSQL, Oracle and not Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `desired_table_name` variable in `command`, you're deleting from a table literally named `desired_table_name`. You can use an f-string there to substitute the variable.

```
    command = "DELETE t1 FROM {desired_table_name} t1 INNER JOIN {desired_table_name} t2 WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID AND t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName AND t1.Surname = t2.Surname AND t1.Size = t2.Size AND t1.Weight = t2.Weight"
```

There's also no need to use an f-string when the replacement is the entire string. So you can change

```
    cursor.execute(f"{command}")
```

to just

```
    cursor.execute(command)
```